# No me corre correctamente un programa con arreglos Java

Tags: java, array, netbeans

```
public class AlumnosA {

    String [] alumnos = new String[2];
    int []calificacion = new int[2];
    String []letra = new String[2];
    String a;
    int c;
    String estatus;
    String cal;


    public void alumno(){
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        System.out.println("Ingresa el nombre del alumno : ");
        a=teclado.next();
        alumnos[i]=a;
   }
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        System.out.println("Ingresa la calificacion de "+alumnos[i]);
        c=teclado.nextInt();
        calificacion[i]=c;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        if(calificacion[i]<7){
            letra[i]="AS";
        }else if(calificacion[i]>=8&& calificacion[i]<=8){
            letra[i]="SA";
        }else if(calificacion[i]>=9&& calificacion[i]<=9){
            letra[i]="DE";
         }else{
            letra[i]="AU";
        }
    }
                for(int ii=0; ii<2; ii++){
        System.out.println(alumnos[ii]+"");
        System.out.println(calificacion[ii]+"");
        System.out.println(letra[ii]+"");
    }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AlumnosA xd = new AlumnosA();
        xd.alumno();



    }
}
```

Después de ingresar el nombre de los alumnos me da el siguiente error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at alumnos.AlumnosA.alumno(AlumnosA.java:34)
    at alumnos.AlumnosA.main(AlumnosA.java:56)
C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 4 seconds)
```

La verdad no sé a que de deba.

Comment: Revisa este enlace de SO en ingles https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027537/why-am-i-getting-inputmismatchexception

Answer (score 1):

El `InputMismatch` ocurre porque aquí:

```
    System.out.println("Ingresa la calificacion de "+alumnos[i]);
    c=teclado.nextInt();
```

no estableces ningún control para obligar a que el usuario escriba un número entero.

Puedes hacerlo de este modo:

```
public class AlumnosA {

    String [] alumnos = new String[2];
    int []calificacion = new int[2];
    String []letra = new String[2];
    String a;
    int c;
    String estatus;
    String cal;


    public void alumno(){
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
            System.out.println("Ingresa el nombre del alumno : ");
            a=teclado.next();
            alumnos[i]=a;
        }

        for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
            System.out.println("Ingresa la calificacion de "+alumnos[i]);

            /*No salimos del bucle hasta que no escriba un entero*/
            while (!teclado.hasNextInt()) {
                teclado.next();
                System.out.println("No escribiste un entero. Por favor ingresa la calificacion de " + alumnos[i] + " correctamente");
            }

            c=teclado.nextInt();
            calificacion[i]=c;
        }
        teclado.close();

        for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
            if(calificacion[i]<7){
                letra[i]="AS";
            }else if(calificacion[i]>=8&& calificacion[i]<=8){
                letra[i]="SA";
            }else if(calificacion[i]>=9&& calificacion[i]<=9){
                letra[i]="DE";
            }else{
                letra[i]="AU";
            }
        }

        for(int ii=0; ii<2; ii++){
            System.out.println(alumnos[ii]+"");
            System.out.println(calificacion[ii]+"");
            System.out.println(letra[ii]+"");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AlumnosA xd = new AlumnosA();
        xd.alumno();
    }

}
```

Hacemos una prueba intentando escribir datos incorrectos:

```
Ingresa el nombre del alumno : 
Pedro
Ingresa el nombre del alumno : 
Juan
Ingresa la calificacion de Pedro
l
No escribiste un entero. Por favor ingresa la calificacion de Pedro correctamente
10
Ingresa la calificacion de Juan
jjjj
No escribiste un entero. Por favor ingresa la calificacion de Juan correctamente
hhhh
No escribiste un entero. Por favor ingresa la calificacion de Juan correctamente
20
Pedro
10
AU
Juan
20
AU
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 32 seconds)
```